# Problem with image from HTML table after slicing and exporting from Photoshop

Tags: html, table, photoshop

I made an image in Photoshop, I used Photoshop slice tool:

[image: Photoshop Slice Tool]

**Original Image:**
[image: Original Image]

I used "Save for Web Devices" option to export each slice tools in PNG images and it creates a page, HTML page. As simple page, the page looks good but when I included in my project, it looks as a fragmented puzzle, look in picture:

[image: fragmented puzzle]

I will paste here the HTML code (with style): http://pastebin.com/U9p3GT5j

This code is a part of complex project and my `style.css` external CSS style doesn't affect that table or I want where I put the slices to place an input text...

Comment: The images don't load for me (slow/bad server?). General tip: slicing images and displaying them in a table is a ancient and bad technique. Since I can't see the images I can't see what you are attempting, but consider learning about modern CSS layouts and use that instead.

Comment: I couldn't connect to the shareimage site. Looking at your code, I would recommend a different strategy for constructing your page. Table layouts are difficult to maintain and style rules should go in a separate CSS file - it will make your life much easier when you need to make changes to your style rather than having to hunt through your markup.

Comment: I changed to imageshack.us host image.

Comment: i think what you need to do is to move on, and start using css, eventually you will see how easier it is. [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/) is a good place to start, not the best but a good place

Comment: I modified and added last phrase...I want to put an input text in every slice created in PS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a table here is what i suggest using

```
table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

this way you will not see the spaces inside the table.